# customize PDF name of report in qweb - odoo

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

How to customize the report PDF name in odoo? for example sale.report_saleorder.pdf into "SO001.pdf" in odoo v8

Answer (score 1):

addons\report\controllers\main.py
Line : 127

```
response.headers.add('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=%s.pdf;' % reportname)
```

change

```
invoicename="ma_facture" #create a variable you can add date for example stfftime("%d-%m-%Y")
response.headers.add('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=%s.pdf;' % invoicename)
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant download this module [Custom report filenames](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/report_custom_filename/)